# Issue while Upgrading the SmartGWT version from 5.0 to 6.0

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I have an application which is developed on SmartGWT. While upgrading SmartGWT 5.0 to 6.0 , This might be easy but no luck .i am getting the below exception
and i am using GWT 2.6.1 , can any one help me out to solve this issue.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.6.1:compile (default) on project px-smartgwt-client: Failed to read module XML file sun
.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream@541afb85: invalid LOC header (bad signature) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.6.1:compile (default) on project px-smartgwt-client: Failed to read module XML file sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream@541afb85
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to read module XML file sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream@541afb85
at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compilationRequired(CompileMojo.java:576)
at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compile(CompileMojo.java:437)
at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.doExecute(CompileMojo.java:351)
at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.AbstractGwtShellMojo.execute(AbstractGwtShellMojo.java:172)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
... 19 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.utils.GwtModuleReaderException: Failed to read module XML file sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream@541afb85
at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.AbstractGwtModuleMojo.readModule(AbstractGwtModuleMojo.java:240)
at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.AbstractGwtModuleMojo.readModule(AbstractGwtModuleMojo.java:194)
at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.GwtModule.getLocalInherits(GwtModule.java:189)
at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.GwtModule.getInherits(GwtModule.java:149)
at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.GwtModule.getEntryPoints(GwtModule.java:114)
at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compilationRequired(CompileMojo.java:490)
... 24 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:61)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:717)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:420)
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.XmlReader.getBOMEncoding(XmlReader.java:635)
at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.XmlReader.doRawStream(XmlReader.java:459)
at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.XmlReader.<init>(XmlReader.java:180)
at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.XmlReader.<init>(XmlReader.java:143)
at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.XmlStreamReader.<init>(XmlStreamReader.java:86)
at org.codehaus.plexus.util.ReaderFactory.newXmlReader(ReaderFactory.java:104)
at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.AbstractGwtModuleMojo.readModule(AbstractGwtModuleMojo.java:233)
... 29 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/d...utionException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve the above issue..Issue is with smartgwt jar is corrupted.. i downloaded the jar from this link ([http://www.smartclient.com/builds/Sm...rtgwt-6.0p.zip](http://I%20am%20able%20to%20solve%20the%20above%20issue..Issue%20is%20with%20smartgwt%20jar%20is%20corrupted..%20i%20downloaded%20the%20jar%20from%20this%20link%20(http://www.smartclient.com/builds/Sm...rtgwt-6.0p.zip)))